# Regexp to fix GPS data

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, regular-expression

I'm looking to fix GPS data in text file on Linux

Incorrect string model: `49:29:37N 005:28:39E`

2or3digits:2or3digits:2or3digits(N|S) 2or3digits:2or3digits:2or3digits(E|W)

Correct string model: `49:29:37 N 005:28:39 E`

2or3digits:2or3digits:2or3digits (N|S) 2or3digits:2or3digits:2or3digits (E|W)

Anyone can help me to do this ?

Thanks

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add a space between the numbers and the letter representing the compass direction, I think this will do it:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{2,3}:[0-9]{2,3}:[0-9]{2,3})([NS])\s+([0-9]{2,3}:[0-9]{2,3}:[0-9]{2,3})([EW])/\1 \2 \3 \4/g' input.txt
```

Or instead of specifying `input.txt`, pipe from stdin, and if you want the output in a file, add `> output.txt` at the end.

This allows any number of spaces or other whitespace characters between the N/S and the number that starts the next coordinate, and outputs a single space in that spot. That can be tweaked if necessary.

EDIT: If some of the input data already have spaces between the coordinate numbers and the direction letters for one of the two coordinates but not both, try:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{2,3}:[0-9]{2,3}:[0-9]{2,3}) *([NS])\s+([0-9]{2,3}:[0-9]{2,3}:[0-9]{2,3}) *([EW])/\1 \2 \3 \4/g' input.txt
```

Comment: Many thanks. I added -i argument to sed to change input file without output in console or to a file.

Comment: Any idea why it didn't work for all lines:

DP 50:18:50 N 003:41:24 E
DP 50:18:39 N 003:41:41E
DP 50:18:26 N 003:42:22E
DP 50:18:29 N 003:42:36E
DP 50:18:30 N 003:42:36 E

Comment: Is that the input or the output? Do some of the lines already have a space in between the coordinates and the compass direction in one of the sides but not the other? (That wasn't specified as a possibility in your question.) If so, see the edit above.

Comment: Many thanks. Your edit work for all lines.

Answer (score 3):

Insert a space before all four possible letters with `sed`:

```
sed 's/[NESW]/ &/g' file
```

Output:

```
49:29:37 N 005:28:39 E
```

Comment: What if there are other N, E, S, or W's in the file?

Comment: @frabjous: This is not specified by him.